# How to save an array of HKQuantitySamples (heart rate) to a workout

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

Apple's docs sample code saves an average heart rate `HKQuantitySample` to a workout via `add` method, however for a given workout I am trying to save all heart rate values taken during the workout, i.e. `[HKQuantitySample]` how can I do this? Below is my code adding the first value just to test, but i want to add them all?

```
 var heartRateValues = [HKQuantitySample]()

 func processHeartRateSamples(_ samples: [HKQuantitySample]) {
        for sample in samples {
            heartRateValues.append(sample)
        }    
    }

private func addSamples(toWorkout workout: HKWorkout, from startDate: Date, to endDate: Date) {
        // Create energy and distance samples
        let totalEnergyBurnedSample = HKQuantitySample(type: HKQuantityType.activeEnergyBurned(),
                                                       quantity: totalEnergyBurnedQuantity(),
                                                       start: startDate,
                                                       end: endDate)

        let totalDistanceSample = HKQuantitySample(type: HKQuantityType.distanceWalkingRunning(),
                                                   quantity: totalDistanceQuantity(),
                                                   start: startDate,
                                                   end: endDate)





        // Add samples to workout
        healthStore.add([totalEnergyBurnedSample, totalDistanceSample, heartRateValues.first!], to: workout) { (success: Bool, error: Error?) in
            guard success else {
                print("Adding workout subsamples failed with error: \(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }


            }
        }
```

Comment: I think you are missing time when each heart rate was recorded...do you have that?

Comment: well I can get by just using `Date` but how will that be incorporated here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have `heartRateValues` as `[HKQuantitySample]` so just do:

```
private func addSamples(toWorkout workout: HKWorkout, from startDate: Date, to endDate: Date) {
    // Create energy and distance samples
    let totalEnergyBurnedSample = HKQuantitySample(type: HKQuantityType.activeEnergyBurned(),
                                                   quantity: totalEnergyBurnedQuantity(),
                                                   start: startDate,
                                                   end: endDate)

    let totalDistanceSample = HKQuantitySample(type: HKQuantityType.distanceWalkingRunning(),
                                               quantity: totalDistanceQuantity(),
                                               start: startDate,
                                               end: endDate)

    let samples = [HKQuantitySample]()
    samples.append(totalEnergyBurnedSample)
    samples.append(totalDistanceSample)
    samples.append(contentsOf: heartRateValues)

    // Add samples to workout
    healthStore.add(samples, to: workout) { (success: Bool, error: Error?) in
        guard success else {
            print("Adding workout subsamples failed with error: \(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }


        }
    }
```

Basically you create an array of samples add `totalEnergyBurnedSample` and `totalDistanceSample` and then whole `heartRateValues` array and then pass that `sample` argument in `healthStore.add` method...